# Smyfony 3 UcWords prior to record insert

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I'm sure this is super simple but I cannot find a explanation of how to do it.  I have a form that asks for the user's name (amongst other things).  Before I insert the record I want to ucwords on the name field.

How do I do this when I am inserting the record thus...

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($profile);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: `$profile->setName(ucwords($profile->getName()));` prior to `$em->flush();`.  Alternatively: You could attach a Doctrine Listener to fire in prePersist / preUpdate for your entity to do your sanitizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is multiple places where you could do this.

**In your entity**

```
classs Profile
{
    //...

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = ucwords($name);
    }
}
```

**In your form**

using a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class);

        $builder->get('name')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($name) {
                    // from model to form (not needed, but won't hurt)
                    return ucwords($name);
                },
                function ($name) {
                    // this is the direction were we need it
                    return ucwords($name);
                },
           ))
    ;
}
```

There are other places, e.g. a [Entity Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html) or form events, but really one of these places is where I would look first. If it's a general requirement that the name is supposed to be uppercased I would go with the setter to make sure it's stored that way as well. If you are not sure all the data is persisted as needed you can put it in the entities getter as well, but even then I would look at making sure to fix the malformed data instead and ensure it's saved in the format you want, unless there are compelling reasons against it.

I wouldn't go with the combination suggested in the comment as this will lead to inconsistent data when someone forgets to call the setter with the ucwords.

Comment: Thank you very much for the full explanation!!! This is my first MVC framework and that is very very helpful :-)